# Gradle task at the end of build with a multiproject build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am attempting to create my own task, that will create a package of all the artifacts generated during my multi-project build.

Currently what I do right is now just:

```
gradle build createPackage
```

Which gives output like the following:

```
:test-utility:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:test-utility:processResources UP-TO-DATE
...
:test-utility:check UP-TO-DATE
:test-utility:build UP-TO-DATE
Creating Package...
Created.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.654 secs
```

With the `createPackage` task being:

```
task createPackage {    
    println "Creating Package..."
    println "Created."
}
```

However, I would like to simply it by running just one command, so what would the best way to do this and ensure the order stays maintained?

Ideally I would like to call `build` within the `createPackage` task or append to the `build` task with my task.

Comment: isn't 'createPackage.dependsOn(build)' what you want?

Comment: Doing what you suggested for a non multi-project project results in the output of 'Creating Package...' showing up immediately following the build command not the end. Also, doing it in a multi-project results in an error. (`Could not find property 'build' on root project`) I have tried playing around with the multi project by setting the last item to build to be the `dependsOn` for `createPackage` but still doesn't have output in the correct position. I assume the `println` output is when it executes, is that not correct?

Comment: No that is not correct, the println will be printed when the task is configured, not when it is executed. To make it print when the task is executed use task createPackage << { println .. }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok reading between the lines there are a few things to clear up

1) Your printlns are being run in the configuration phase, not the execution phase. See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html for more info.

2) You do not have a single 'build' task. `gradle build` on the command line will run the 'build' task of each of your subprojects. Your package task would need to depend on all of them. Something like..

```
apply plugin: 'java'
evaluationDependsOnChildren()
task createPackage(type:Zip) {
   dependsOn subprojects*.build
}
```

3) You can be more declarative with gradle - just tell it what you want to package up and it will figure out what it needs to run. For example, you can say that you want to zip up all the jars from your subprojects.

```
apply plugin: 'java'    
evaluationDependsOnChildren()
task createPackage(type:Zip) {
   from subprojects*.jar
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reading between the lines and clearing it up regarding the println executions. I've adjusted it so the task is `task createPackage(dependsOn: subprojects*.build) << { ... }` which works nicely and prints out with where I expect it to during the execution. I used the createPackage as a simple example as to how I build the package and the contents will involve more logic than zip everything.

Comment: Cool. For 3) I was just using Zip as a simple example of that approach. If you set up inputs on your task you could use the same approach (if you so desired)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways. One suggestion is to modify `build` to depend on `createPackage` to make sure you can call just `gradle build`. Then you want to enhance your task and tell what are its inputs (probably those are outputs of some other tasks like `jar`). Gradle will add these tasks to execution when you run the build and can re-run them based on up-to-date status of each task. This is documented in userguide - [http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec%3aup_to_date_checks) and later in a chapter on custom tasks.

Comment: Wouldn't making `build` depend on `createPackage` cause it to execute potentially first and not last since in order for `build` to execute it must run the `createPackage` task first. 

Also this doesn't quite work for a multi-project build as there exists multiple builds for each subproject that implements the `java` plugin.

I have been playing around with the depends on and trying to get the ordering to work properly in a multi-project build but it isn't working from what I've seen with where the `println`'s get displayed in the `gradle build` output.

Comment: BTW: your testing task should be like 
`task createPackage << {    
    println "Creating Package..."
    println "Created."
}` to execute when action is run and not in configuration phase. Build time will be affected only when the outputs need to be rebuild. It is your choice. Of course you can also run tasks like `assemble`